# accessing the home screen and opening a new application without exiting the one open on Android phone

Tags: android

assume program1 is open. I want to access to the home screen and  open program2 without closing program1.

How to do this?

my Samsung galaxy note has a home button, but when I push it while a program is open only recent apps I use can be reached.

Thx
Ozi

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for:

> If an activity has lost focus but is still visible (that is, a new non-full-sized or transparent activity has focus on top of your activity), it is paused. A paused activity is completely alive (it maintains all state and member information and remains attached to the window manager), but can be killed by the system in extreme low memory situations.
>
> If an activity is completely obscured by another activity, it is stopped. It still retains all state and member information, however, it is no longer visible to the user so its window is hidden and it will often be killed by the system when memory is needed elsewhere.

In other words, if your application is not in the first plan, the system will decide if this must be closed or not (depending on your system resources)

Please check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for more details.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an answer to my question. I ask how to open a new app without closing the current one myself.

Comment: Pushing the home button as you indicate above will leave the previous application running but in a paused state. You can open a second application by pushing the application icon in the applications menu. This menu will usually be visible to you from the home view.

As was mentioned above, the first application will continue to run until Android determines that it needs to be closed to preserve memory.

Comment: In my phone when I push the home button I just get a list of last 6 apps I used before, plus a button that opens the task manager. How can I get to applications menu you mention?

Comment: What is your android version?

Comment: it is version 2.3.6 . I don't know its name.

Comment: I guess that when you say you are only able to see the last six apps, you mean you had kept the home button pressed for a while, is that correct? This is the way to see the running activities. Notice you can always press the same icon that opened your application, and if the app is still in memory, this will come back in the last state.

Comment: Oh this is it thanks.. I just needed to push the home button briefly instead of holding it pressed. Thx.

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to accept the correct answer and close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Unless an app is designed to run in the background, it can't be "minimized" on Android. To open another app, the current app must pause or exit.